# tiny scrollbar inside pop up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

For some reason tinyscrollbar is not working when I keep it inside a parent element.

Here is the plane tiny scroll bar **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AA7bw/1/)** - This works fine

And this is the problem with the pop up div **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GknfT/3/)**

```
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `scrollbar()` after `click()`

```
$('#test').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').show();
    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();   
     $('#overlay').show();
});
```

[**DEMO**] `-->` (http://jsfiddle.net/GknfT/4/)

Comment: No wait that is not an issue. I accidentally forgot to attach. let me give you updated version

Comment: Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/GknfT/3/ and click on open pop text then you can se the pop in which tinyscrollbar is not working